# How can I start Windows on a different physical drive that has a copied partition?

Tags: windows, boot, boot-partition

I recently installed Windows 10, and I wanted to compare the time it takes to boot on an SSD and an HDD. For inexplicable reasons, I figured that if I copy my :C partition on my SSD and create a duplicate partition on my HDD and boot from my HDD, I will start Windows from my HDD. But to me, it seems that no matter which drive I boot from, I always start Windows from the :C partition. Was my method in wrong that I just simply copy and paste an OS partition? If so, how can I correctly copy Windows to the HDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying is not enough. You also have to add the new OS to the Bootmanager. If you had just installed it regularly on a partition on the HDD (this is what i recommend btw) this entry would have been added automatically. This way you have to add it manually.

Microsoft has an article about how to do that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541231(v=vs.85).aspx). This is for Win7 and Win8.1 but Win10 works the same way as far as i could test it right now.